# Load only first 10 posts, then load more - parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm having a post-feed where I load my posts from a parse database. All posts are saved and loaded from one class.

Now, when the app launches and the user opened the post-feed, I want to load only the first 10 posts (sorted by date).
After that, when I'm at the bottom table cell, I want to load the next 10 posts. Can be done by pressing a "Load More" button or by scrolling at the bottom and it automatically loads more.

I use swift in xCode.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: using swift or ObjC ?

Comment: @Mehul is that relevant?

Comment: @Fogmeister, no my friend, i does't know, how to implemented in swift.

Answer (score 3):

`PFQuery` has a `limit` property and a `skip` property.

These are listed in the docs under "Paginating Results".

For the first ten you set `skip` to 0 and `limit` to 10.

For the next ten you set `skip` to 10 and `limit` to 10.

And so on...

You can read more detail by looking at [the documentation for PFQuery](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html).

To add your results to the existing results.

First have an array to store the results.

```
var results = [MyObject]()
```

Then when the results come back from parse currently you will be doing something like this...

```
results = theArrayReturnedFromParse
```

This will set the array to be only the ten from parse. You need to do this...

```
results += theArrayReturnedFromParse
```

This will add the new results to the array and keep the old ones.

Comment: This answer is correct. It should be noted that if you implement Parse's native pagination that comes with `PFQueryTableViewController` then you don't have to do the skipping yourself, but you do have to set the `limit`.

Comment: Yes, I already read from these properties. But I don't know how to add the next 10 posts to my tableView without deleting the first 10 cells.

Comment: @pbush25 ah cool. I haven't ever used the `PFQueryTableViewController` as I usually roll my own with my own cloud function instead of a query. But good to know :D

Comment: @BenggerApplications as I mentioned, if you're using `PFQueryTableViewController` then you simply have to set the `paginationEnabled = true` when initializing the VC. If you're not using this, then you will have to use the `skip` function, and use the answer that @Fogmeister provided in their edit.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good. Do you guys think this will work on my tableViewController? You can see the code of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996907/how-to-sort-my-tableview-by-createdat-parse @Fogmeister